# How to find the IBM/DB2 SQL0104 Token issue?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

Here is the statement that I am trying to call:

```sql
SELECT
    Test_Data.PRDINVSEQ.DASTAT, 
    DACUST, 
    DASRNO, 
    DADTOR, 
    DAORNO, 
    Test_Data.bthdrextpf.SHXDEP, 
    DADNAM, 
    DADTST, 
    CASE WHEN DACONF = '' THEN 'N' ELSE DACONF END AS DACONF1, 
    DAENGD, 
    DAEXTC, 
    DAPRGY, 
    Test_Data.BTHDR.SHSPL1, 
    DASPRD, 
    DADTCD, 
    DALDNO, 
    DADTLD, 
    DADTMD, 
    DAMDLN, 
    Test_Data.PRDINVSEQ.STATSQ
FROM Test_Data.BTHDR 
JOIN Test_Data.DLRINVAPF ON SHORNO = DAORNO 
JOIN Test_Data.PRDINVSEQ ON Test_Data.DLRINVAPF.DASTAT = Test_Data.PRDINVSEQ.DASTAT 
JOIN Test_Data.BTHDREXTPF ON SHORNO = SHXORNO 
WHERE  TRIM(DACUST)<>'' AND Test_Data.DLRINVAPF.DASTAT IN ('WP', 'OD', 'SC', 'BO')
ORDER BY DADNAM, Test_Data.PRDINVSEQ.STATSQ ASC, DADTST ASC, DAMDLN ASC
```

The error doesn't make sense to me:

```
[SQL0104] Token   was not valid. Valid tokens: ( + * - ? : DAY INF LAG NAN RID ROW RRN CASE CAST CHAR DATE DAYS.
```

Notice that there are 3 spaces between **Token** and **was**.

I am more of a Microsoft SQL developer. Any pointers or suggestions for using IBM/DB2 are appreciated, but I need to get this IBM/DB2 query running.

Could someone explain this error to me?

**SOLVED:**

I had identical SQL that was working fine, but it was organized differently. I spent way too long working to get both versions of the SQL looking identical while one side was working but the other side was not.

[image: Beyond Compare]

In the end, it appears that I had some sort of non-printable character code at the end of my SQL statement.

[image: character code]

As best I can tell, this is what caused the SQL not to run on the IBM/DB2.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error here, how is it run. Using *Run SQL script* in [IBM ACS](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions) will position the cursor where the error is found

Comment: @nfgl, yeah, I was hoping someone would understand that error. As for ACS, I tried installing it once, but it takes IT help, and our IT guy didn't understand it. He gave me Data Studio client instead.

Answer (score 1):

Three part naming (Test_Data.PRDINVSEQ.DASTAT) points to a database called Test_Data, a table called PRDINVSEQ, and a column called DASTAT. If Test_Data is actually a schema, drop it from the *column* references and leave it on the *table* references.

Reference:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=request-three-part-names
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=names-qualified-column